# What information does a GPU core dump contain, and how can it be used for debugging?

Tags: linux, debugging, gpu, openmp, coredump

I am new to GPU programming. I just wanted to know what extra information does a GPU core dump contain compared to a CPU core dump? How do I debug through a GPU core file?

Thanks in advance.